# ASP.NET MVC Displaying Static Help Website

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add Help to my ASP.NET MVC project.

The "help" website contains static pages about the features in my ASP.NET application.

I have added the content for this website into my ASP.NET MVC project and have added a hyperlink that will open the Help in its own window.

However, when I try to access the content, the application attempts to route to the Help controller.

How do I display the help website within my MVC application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use IgnoreRoute when you configre your routing, for example, create a folder "help" in your app's root. Then load it with all your html help files. Then to ignore that route:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("help");
```

You should then be able to access it by `http://myapp.com/help/whatever.html`

Comment: Had to also add every sub folder into the ignore routes but this was the solution in the end

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you can do this within the context of an MVC application.  I would consider just building an empty controller with an Index action (HelpController -> public ActionResult Index()) and just return the view name (cshtml file), shouldn't be any reason you can't rename your static html file to cshtml even if you aren't using razor (although I am not 100% sure without trying that the extension change is necessary).  Also I would argue that if this ever needs more functionality you have the scaffolding in place to make non-static mods.  Disabling routing within the context of an MVC solution honestly doesn't make the most logical sense.  The only other choice would be if you hosted it in a different IIS site (but I don't think I would recommend that unless you have a huge help library).

Comment: I'm not really happy about the idea of making a whole website for the help because of the nature of this application and how it is going to be deployed.

Comment: As I said a separate site is definitely overkill but you will need a controller/route to display a view

Comment: I used the IgnoreRout method and was able to accomplish this